# IE 9 - 30 Second Ajax POST Requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, internet-explorer-9

In IE 9, when sending an AJAX request to my server using either of the following methods

```
// SproutCore
SC.Request.postUrl(...).send()

// jQuery
$.post(...)
```

I am always seeing a nearly 30 second delay before the function returns, even though I can clearly see in WireShark that the request is received. It's been a while since I've used Wireshark, so perhaps I'm just reading it wrong, but I see the following, which makes me think this may be an Apache issue perhaps?

```
Time         Info
-------------------------------------------------------------------
77.716243    [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1031 Win=7808 Len=896
107.576027   [FIN, ACK] Seq=897 Ack=1032 Win=7808 Len=0
```

Notice an almost exact 30 second difference. Also, I have confirmed that the first request contains the correct data from the server.

Is this just a bug in IE 9? Or perhaps a misconfiguration on my Apache server?

Any thoughts would be *greatly* appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried this in other browsers? IE9 _is_ IE after all, so it's amazing if anything works well. IE9 is a slight improvement, but it's coming off a low base.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and takes a few seconds in IE8, but is usually in the 2-6 second range.

Comment: What are you requesting? Could there be some html errors etc in it? IE has a problem with correcting errors on ajax request :(

Comment: I'm requesting some basic JSON. As far as I can tell it's perfectly valid. And everything works perfectly after the 30 second delay.

Comment: For future reference, fiddler (www.fiddertool.com) is a much better tool than wireshark for debugging this type of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm...looks like this was a non-issue. Apparently restarting my computer fixed the issue, so it isn't a code-level problem. Sorry to dump this into the SO-sphere. Hopefully, though, someone else will see this and restart before posting a question :-)

**Update:** I'm again experiencing the error, but I think it is server related, so I've opened a [question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/331702/ie-ajax-request-times-out-even-though-server-is-responding).

**Update x2:** Well, not a real solution, but I found a workaround by using the following code:

```
didSend: function(request, response) {
  if (SC.browser.msie && request.get('type') === "POST") {
    setTimeout(function() {
      Core360.Request.getUrl('/test_server').send();
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

For some reason, this forces the previous connection to close, and apparently the GET request immediately returns and isn't pending, so it works.

I hope this helps some poor soul in the future.